# Translation of 所属事務所

Tags: translation

I'm translating this and stuck on the meaning of 所属事務所でも, I can't work out if it's an affiliated office, an office he's affiliated to, or something else. I've exhausted searching my usual sources and have decided to ask a question here. Many thanks!

> 私は、インフラストラクチャービジネス（IB）に対する強い関心と会計士としての高い能力が認められ、現在は**所属事務所でも**1位の売上高を誇るプラントエンジニアリング会社のインチャージとして10名超の監査チームをマネジメントしている。

Currently I have a very strong interest in Infrastructure Business (IB), and my strong abilities as an accountant have been recognized. Currently in my capacity as head of the plant engineering company, which boasts top sales even though an affiliated office, I manage an auditing team of more than 10 persons.

Answer (score 1):

所属事務所 refers to the office he (the speaker) belongs to. インチャージ here is a wasei-eigo jargon noun that means (主な)担当者, 責任者 or "(primary) person in charge". See: [「インチャージ」という役割](http://uscpa-accounting.com/?p=166)

"所属事務所でも1位の売上高を誇る" and "プラントエンジニアリング会社の" each independently modifies インチャージ.

- 所属事務所でも1位の売上高を誇るインチャージとして
  as a person (in charge) who boasts the top sales in my office
- プラントエンジニアリング会社のインチャージとして
  as a person in charge of a plant engineering company

(**EDIT**: Alternatively you can think 所属事務所でも1位の売上高を誇る modifies プラントエンジニアリング会社のインチャージ as a whole: "as a person in charge of a plant engineering company who boasts the top sales in my office")

If I understand correctly, he is not directly employed by that plant engineering company, is he? I think he says that he belongs to some auditing/accounting/consulting office and currently is in charge of the engineering company as the manager of the auditing team.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's cleared that up. I was thinking that 誇る modified プラントエンジニアリング which was causing confusion.  I ended up going for this:  Currently I am in charge of the plant engineering company and I manage an auditing team of more than 10 staff; I am also proud to say I have the top sales in my office.              Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user18083 I agree that this is certainly a confusing sentence. Actually I also initially read this as something like "number-one plant engineering company in my office", but it makes no sense, of course.